# How to properly use guards in Haskell?

Tags: list, function, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying to write simple functions to get myself used to the syntax, I want to write my own function for adding a certain element to a list at a specific index. Here's what I wrote in Atom (my text editor):

```hs
addElem :: a->[a]->Int->[a]
addElem elem list index
 | index <= 0            = elem:list
 | index < (length list) = a ++ (elem:b) where a = take index list; b = drop index list
 | otherwise             = list
```

The idea is that it won't freak out as long as index is an `Int` and `elem` is of the same type as the elements of `list`, but when I try to load this into ghci I get "parse error on `|'." Do I need to constrain the types of the arguments? I'm reading Learn You A Haskell but I haven't gotten to the part where they fully explain how the indentations work, so my error might also be there.

Comment: A `where` block is not attached to an expression, i.e. `x where decls` is not an expression (in contrast to `let decls in x`, which is an expression). A `where` block must be attached to a declaration, in this case you presumably want it attached to the `addElem` declaration, and so must be placed *after* the declaration body, of which the last guard statement also forms part. Note that parse errors never have to do with using the wrong type - it means the compiler doesn't even understand your code, let alone judge it to be wrong. This also is not an indentation error.

Comment: @user2407038 that should be an answer

Comment: Do you really mean to ignore `elem` if `index` is too big? That's a bit asymmetrical compared to prepending the element when `index` is < 0. I would think `otherwise = list ++ [elem]` would make sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`where` blocks need to occur at the end of the whole function, and are shared amongst all the cases. You probably meant to use a `let`:

```
addElem :: a -> [a] -> Int -> [a]
addElem elem list index
 | index <= 0            = elem:list
 | index < (length list) = let a = take index list; b = drop index list in a ++ (elem:b)
 | otherwise             = list
```

Also, note that `let` could be written more concisely as `let (a,b) = splitAt index list in ...`. [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:splitAt) is also in the Prelude. Of course, you could also just move the `where` block to the end of the function (Haskell's laziness makes this easy to reason about).

```
addElem :: a -> [a] -> Int -> [a]
addElem elem list index
 | index <= 0            = elem:list
 | index < (length list) = a ++ (elem:b)
 | otherwise             = list
 where
   a = take index list
   b = drop index list
```

Personally, I like this less because it suggests that `a` and `b` may be used elsewhere in the function.

Section 4.4.3 of the [2010 Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-620004) goes into more detail on where `where` is allowed.